# Curl bypass reCAPTCHA with white list of sites

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, web-crawler, recaptcha

How can I bypass this recaptcha of this site with PHP + Curl ??? I tried to display it for the visitor to solve but it has a whitelist of websites and an error occurs. What are my other options?

recaptcha page
http://servicos.receita.fazenda.gov.br/Servicos/cnpjreva/Cnpjreva_Solicitacao.asp?cnpj=

error:

[image]

"ERROR for site owner:
invalid domain for site key"

Comment: Preventing the bypass of captcha is kinda the whole point of captcha. You're likely violating the Terms of Service for that site by trying.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to display it for the visitor to solve but it has a whitelist of websites and an error occurs.

You cannot set a reCaptcha from a certain website to another setting/other site and make it work. Each reCaptcha is bound to its owner website by `site-key` and is checked with appropriate `secret key`. Read [here](http://webscraping.pro/insert-configure-recaptcha-no-captcha-code-in-php/) for reference.

Comment: I do not agree. That site (https://www.croxyproxy.com/) can make it work. All Anti Captcha sites are also able to make it work. There is some way.

Comment: @BrunoAndrade, how does this site do it? Please explain in general.

Comment: It is an online proxy site. And if you put this site on it http://noise.combr.co/ (a test site of mine) you will see that it can display the recaptcha as on the original site. And everything is functional. I'm trying to find out how they do it, but it's something incredible.